# mysql does not return right value

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need some help. Mysql database is working. My table name is `choice` and `id1` is set to off

But it seems this code here does not return off.

How can I get the code to return the value of id1 ?

so if it return off, it will execute. ?

Like:
if (value from database id1 == off) { do this }

```
       $query3=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM choice WHERE id=1");
       $query4=mysqli_fetch_array($query3);
       if ($query4['choice'] == off) {
           $output = shell_exec('sudo python test1.py');
       }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the exact names of your table and columns? You're referring to a table and a column named "choice" and also to a row "id1" (no idea what that means, assume it is id=1) and you probably have a column id that has the value 1 in the row youre looking for

Comment: Database=my_db - Table=choice - columns=id | name, where id=1 and name=off

Comment: I updated my answer with that information, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table is named "choice" and has two columns named "id" and "name" and you want to check the row that has id=1 and name="off", I would recommend this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM choice WHERE id=1";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
if ($result['name'] == "off")
{
    $output = shell_exec('sudo python test1.py');
}
```

Or even better:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM choice WHERE id=1 AND name='off'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
    $output = shell_exec('sudo python test1.py');
}
```